# Place a picture box inside another: VS2008

Tags: vb.net, transparency, picturebox

hope i can get some help here. 
For a VB app, I try to place one picturebox over GDI+ drawn image (or another picturebox) in visual studio 2008, and the picturebox includes transparent areas which don't come up transparent.

I have looked through many methods but they don't suit my situation: 
a background is drawn using GDI, and for my app I need a picturebox stationary upon it. (the stationary image cant be GDI+ drawn too, because the background updates every while, which causes it to disappear. tried to redraw image also but it makes an ugly flickering effect).

when i try to use picturebox as background, and assign it as parent for the overlaying image for transparency effect, the above image doesn't show at all. here is the VB code:

```vb
Dim back As PictureBox
Dim silhouetteAs PictureBox
Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap(imgPath)
img.MakeTransparent(Color.White)
back = New PictureBox()
silhouette= New PictureBox()
silhouette.Parent = back
silhouette.Size = New Point(width, height)
silhouette.Location = New Point(xpos, ypos)
silhouette.Image = img
silhouette.BackColor = Color.Transparent
back.Parent = MAIN
back.Size = New Point(width, height)
back.Location = New Point(xpos, ypos)
back.BackColor = Color.Blue
```

where back is the background and silhouette is the on-top image.
can someone please provide an example of how transparency achieved through parenting pictureboxes? or any other solution to this situation?

Comment: I cant figure out which of three possible issues you want help with

Comment: I need a way to have a picturebox with transparent areas over any other image. any way would be appreciated. I only listed out the issues to show that i know the different methods, but they arent helpful to me (or im doing it wrong)

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to accomplish?  What is the PictureBox for?  It sounds like PictureBox is the wrong choice for whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found out what was wrong - when I assigned another picturebox as a parent, I didn't update the location of the overlaying picturebox relatively. the correction would be to
add:

```vb
silhouette.location=new point(0,0)
```

forgot that the coordinates are relative to the parent and not the form anymore.

Comment: you cant place one picturebox "inside another" (title) because the picturebox does not have a controls collection; perhaps you are drawing the image from one to another, but that code is not shown. But this wont allow the image behind to show thru in transparent areas unless you **are** drawing 2 images into onw control manually.  - confused

Comment: to sum up, what i needed was one picturebox to overlay another and not to show transparent parts. when i assigned one picturebox as parent the first one disappeared. now i found out that i didnt update the coordinates relatively to the new parent